# Does this circuit need any additional protection? Arduino to Pressure Transducer

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, circuit-protection, transducer

So I'm powering and reading a [Honeywell Pressure Transducer](https://sensing.honeywell.com/MLH08KPSB01A-Stainless-Steel-Media-Isolated-Pressure-Sensors) from my Arduino Mega board. I've got the circuit wired up as shown in the schematic below with the Excitation line from the Transducer going to the 5V on the Arduino, the Common to the Gnd, and the Output to one of my Arduino analog input pins. Currently when I read the transducer over the analog pin it is giving me mostly reasonable values but I wanted to see if I need any resistors in line or anything else to protect both the Arduino and the transducer. What should I check in the future to determine this on my own?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sensor outputs a voltage you're reading through the analog input of you arduino. In analog input the resistance of that pin is really high (I think you can check it on arduino's data sheet) so the current supplied by the transducer is really low. 
So you shouldn't have trouble about damaging your arduino or the transducer as far as you respect their max volt ratings, the only thing you should worry about between the transducer and the input is an analog filter in case you need to get rid of noise and unwanted signals or DC offsets.

Comment: Do you know what kind of filter is typically used on Arduinos? It looks like there are a couple libraries that do digitally mimic some analog filters, for example: http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Filters. Do you think that over sampling and averaging would be effective in this case?

Comment: The most common filter is a DC coupling if you're reading AC and DC decoupling if you're reading DC, after that it totally depends on the application, the type of sensor, the environment, noises from external devices, noises from internal devices, and a long long list of possible factors.

Comment: Okay good to know, I'll look into it a bit more!

Comment: Good to go! Any question feel free to ask